# jni method dynamic register failed

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I'm trying to register my method dynamically like this:

```
int ReadFromAsset(JNIEnv *env,jclass thiz,jobject assetM,jstring, filename)
```

My description about the method in  JNI in a `gMethods[]` is following:

```
{"ReadFromAsset_Native", "(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;Ljava/lang/String)I",(int*)ReadFromAsset}
```

and my description in JAVA is following:

```
 public native void ReadAsset_Native(AssetManager assetM, String filename);
```

Here is the complete code for the register process:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    JNIEnv* env = NULL; 
    jint result = JNI_FALSE;  /*reusult=0*/
    if (vm->GetEnv((void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK) {
        return result;          
    }                               
    if (env == NULL) {  
        return result;              
    }                                   

    if (env->RegisterNatives(clazz, gMethods, sizeof(gMethods) / sizeof(gMethods[0])) < 0) {
        return result;    /*failed  result=0*/ 
    }                                       
    result = JNI_VERSION_1_4;   
    return result; 
}
```

This code is in a .cpp file. And the `ReadFromAsset` as a member method added to. Am I doing something wrong here? Method signature maybe?

Comment: "ReadFromAsset_Native" -> "ReadAsset_Native"

Comment: ok,,my fault,Thanks very much. and I doubt that the  "Landroid/content/res/AssetManager"  is right??

Comment: use `javap -s` then, most likely you need `;` at the end

Comment: thanks for your advice， I will try it。